# Makefile variable printing empty despite definition structure

Tags: makefile

I am working on a C++ library where I am following the structure below:

```
ROOTDIR = ~/path/to/proj
BLDDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/build
INCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/include
SRCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/src
LIBSRCDIR = $(SRCDIR)/lib
TESTSRCDIR = $(SRCDIR)/test
OBJDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/obj
LIBOBJDIR = $(OBJDIR)/lib
TESTOBJDIR = $(OBJDIR)/test
LIBDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/lib
BINDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/bin
```

And the file definitions are:

```
MKFILE = $(BLDDIR)/Makefile
HDRFILES = $(wildcard $(INCDIR)/*.hpp)
LIBSRCFILES := $(wildcard $(LIBSRCDIR)/*.cpp)
TESTSRC = $(TESTSCRCDIR)/test.cpp
LIBOBJFILES := $(patsubst $(LIBSRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(LIBOBJDIR)/%.o, $(LIBSRCFILES))
TESTOBJ := $(TESTOBJDIR)/test.o
LIBFILE = $(LIBDIR)/$(NAME)-$(VERSION).a
TESTFILE = $(BINDIR)/test
ZIPFILE = $(ROOTDIR)/$(NAME).$(VERSION).zip
```

I have tested & confirmed that everything works, but for some reason `$(TESTSRC)` is printing empty even though Make is able to set `$(TESTOBJ)`. I tried setting up the variable definitions in the hierarchy to ensure everything is generated in level, but that one variable remains empty.

EDIT 1:

- Make is finding all of the directories properly
- I have made sure that the file extension is correct
- The variable is not being overwritten

EDIT 2:
The specific error I"mg getting is:
`make: *** No rule to make target /test.cpp', needed by ..../test.o`

..../test.o is in the right directory & defined separately without being dependent on a patsubst like the libsrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully:

```
TESTSRCDIR = $(SRCDIR)/test
    ^^^
```

and:

```
TESTSRC = $(TESTSCRCDIR)/test.cpp
                ^^^
```

Comment: Damn. Foiled by own quick fingers.

Comment: You are assigning `$(VARNAME)/test.cpp` and make is printing `/test.cpp`, so it's very clear that the problem is that the variable `VARNAME` is expanding to the empty string.  So the thing to ask yourself is, why is that variable not set?  Since you think you did set it, the obvious answer is that the variable that was set and the variable that was used are actually not the same variable.